# Picasso prints JPG error for PNG file

Tags: android, picasso

My application works fine but I found something strange in my logs. When I open PNG file that I just generated Picasso prints it has troubles to open JPEG image:

```
10-13 18:15:41.883 10275-10615/lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug I/ExifInterface_JNI: Raw image not detected
10-13 18:15:41.885 10275-10615/lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug W/ExifInterface: Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file(ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) or a corrupted JPEG file to ExifInterface.
at android.media.ExifInterface.getJpegAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1830)
at android.media.ExifInterface.loadAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1474)
at android.media.ExifInterface.<init>(ExifInterface.java:1111)
at com.squareup.picasso.FileRequestHandler.getFileExifRotation(FileRequestHandler.java:46)
at com.squareup.picasso.FileRequestHandler.load(FileRequestHandler.java:42)
at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
```

The picture is generated with:

```
File file = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), figure.getId() + ".png");
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
log.debug("Saving picture bitmap to " + file.getAbsolutePath());
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, fos);
fos.close();
```

Picture is loaded with this code:

```
File file = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), figure + ".png");
if (file.exists()) {
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(file).into(view);
} else {
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(resource).into(view);
}
```

I downloaded this picture and I can see PNG header in binary view. Windows can open it, XnView fails. Any idea what is wrong there?

[image: generated file]

Comment: Please post the code that is generating the exception.

Comment: I added code that loads the picture, but exception is thrown asynchronously. When I place a breakpoint there the exception is shown once I resume the program.

Comment: What is the value of `figure`? If it had a `.jpeg` in that string, I could see where Picasso might get confused.

Comment: No, it shall not. Figure is Vilma. It is called this way:         loadFigurePicture("Vilma", R.drawable.drs_vilma_base, buttonVilma);

Comment: Your Java stack trace is a warning, not an error. What are the symptoms, beyond just getting a warning in LogCat?

Comment: I had a typo in the first sentence - my app is working fine, not file. I do not see any symptoms. But it is really weird and I worry that there may be some bug.

Comment: :: shrug :: I agree that posting a stack trace from a warning is unusual. However, if you worry about all strange output from libraries, you will never get any apps written... :-)

Comment: `Picasso prints it has troubles to open JPEG image:`. No. Not at all. Picasso just blindly tries to extract an exif header/interface from the image. And then you can read the warning that exif is only for jpg. Pngs do not contain an exif. Thats all. You probably would get the same warning for a jpg without exif.